# Online sorting/percentile

Tags: c++

My question is: the program generates a new number as time goes. Every time I want to know the percentile of the number in the sequence. I think we need some online sorting program, so that the process is fast (log n I suppose). I vaguely remember heap sorting would do the job. I wonder whether there are any existing packages (C++ STL for example) for this job.

Comment: you can use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` to find the position to insert an element in an already sorted container (note: an empty container is already sorted)

Comment: Will still be O(n) (either the insertion or the calculation of the percentile). Nothing obvious to me that would achieve O(log n).

Comment: I vaguely remember online heap sorting is O(log n) every step in average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), a data structure that stores items in sorted order and lets you determine the rank (position in sorted order) of new items. Each operation takes time O(log n) to complete, since it's layered on top of a balanced tree (typically, a red/black tree).

Hope this helps!